# Batch: Wildcard for folder

Tags: batch-file, scripting

i want to copy a file from `%LOCALAPPDATA%Low\Oracle\Java\jre*\jre*.msi` to `\\SERVER\NETLOGON` via `batch`.

the folder jre looks like this: `\jre1.8.0_66`
the problem is that there are two folders, `\jre1.8.0_66_x64` and `\jre1.8.0_66` 
how can i exclude `_x64` from copying? after copying i want to delete both folders.

can you help me?

sincerely,
alex

Comment: One possible solution would be to use `XCOPY` with the `/EXCLUDE` option.

Comment: `for /D %%G in ("%LOCALAPPDATA%Low\Oracle\Java\jre*") do (echo %%~nxG)` could be possible start point for your script. Learn [EnableDelayedExpansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html). Then, instead of simple `echo`: use `set "folder=%%~nxG"` and test last four characters, e.g. `if /I NOT "!folder:~-4!"=="_x64" (copy /B "%%G\jre*.msi" "\\SERVER\NETLOGON\")`. Feel free to [edit] your question, add your code, ask more...

Comment: @Squashman but `jre*` could vary depending on currently installed version   and `/EXCLUDE` option claims on (static) file: you need to _fulfil_ that file...

Comment: @JosefZ, I do not see that as a stumbling block to solve the problem. Not difficult to echo your strings to a temporary text file at the beginning of your script.

Comment: @Squashman again: `jre*` could vary: being `jre1.8.0_66` today, could be `jre1.8.0_67` tomorrow... Still need to get it _dynamically_.

Comment: @JosefZ, I am not following your logic at all. The JRE version being different every day would not be a problem.  The question says he wants to EXCLUDE the folder ending in _x64.  We are not putting the JRE version into the exclude.  We are putting _x64 into the exclude.

Comment: @JosefZ thanks, it works for me.